# C++ & Qt: Don't pick a random number for x minutes

Tags: c++, qt, random, time

Let's say i have 10 numbers from 1 to 10 and rand() picks number 3. The number will be displayed on my screen, **but won't be shown for another 15 minutes after it was picked**. How can i do that?

I know srand should be used for better random results, but that's not what I want to achieve. I want a specific number to be shown once, but after that it will not appear until 15 minutes are gone.
I've read something about sleep, but I haven't figured out how that works and if it fits to my problem.

Comment: Qt should have timer events, just schedule such an event 15 minutes into the future and display the value then. [`QTimer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html) seems like a good place to start looking.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to pick a random number from a certain range (say 1-10), but exclude any numbers that were picked up in the most recent 15 minutes?

Comment: So at the beginning I have 10 numbers and if rand picks for example "3" randomly, it will be displayed but after that you won't see that number again for 15 minutes. Which means that during the 15 minutes there are actually just 9 numbers left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One straightforward way: Keep a record of numbers as they're picked and the time they're picked.

So each time you want to display a number:

1. check the record and remove any entries older than 15 minutes.
2. pick a number between 1 and 10.
3. check the record to see if the picked number has been used in the last fifteen minutes. If so then go back to step one.
4. Since the picked number hasn't been used in the last 15 minutes, display the number.
5. Add a new entry to the record for the picked number and the current time.

Note that obviously, if you pick 9 numbers in less than 15 minutes, and the tenth number is also about to be picked within that 15 minutes, the result is not random at all. The point being that with this kind of constraint the results get less random as more numbers get picked within the 15 minute window until there's no randomness left.

Also, after 10 numbers have been picked in the 15 minute window, there are no numbers left, so the loop trying to find a number than hasn't been picked will just spin until some records get removed. And then it will have to pick whatever number is available. That could mean that the same sequence of numbers will be used every 15 minutes, over and over.

---

`srand()` is not a function for producing better random data than `rand()`. Those two functions work together: `srand()` sets the seed value used to produce a random sequence and `rand()` is what actually produces the values. `srand()` doesn't produce better values or do anything to make `rand()` produce 'better' values. It just allows you to select a *different* sequence of values.

If you want something better, look into the C++ `<random>` header or perhaps a [third-party](http://www.pcg-random.org/) [library](http://www.pcg-random.org/posts/ease-of-use-without-loss-of-power.html).

The real benefit of the C++ `<random>` header is the distributions: Instead of having to figure out how to produce random numbers yourself (often using `%`, which is almost always a bad idea), you can simply use e.g. `std::uniform_int_distribution<>(1, 10)` which will correctly produce a number between one and 10.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main() {
  // prepare a reasonable source of randomness
  std::random_device r;
  std::seed_seq seed{r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r()};
  std::mt19937 pRNG(seed);

  // produce 50 random values between one and ten
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> one_to_ten(1, 10);

  for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
    std::cout << one_to_ten(pRNG) << "\n";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a table where you can store the pairs `(time, number)`. Whenever you're ready to generate a new number, you'll need to:

1. Dump values that are too old from the table.
2. Generate a random number that isn't in the table. This can be done by either:

   - Generating a number, checking if it's in the table, and retrying if it is.
   - Generating a number from a smaller range, and mapping it to the larger range that had the numbers present in the table removed from it. Say the table has 10 entries, and your full range is 1-50. You'll then generate numbers in the range 1-40, since 10 numbers in the table are off-limits. You then need to do the mapping.
3. Add the `(current time, number from #2 above)` to the table.

Something like the below might be a starting point:

```
class Generator {
  QMap<QDateTime, int> m_map;
  QSet<int> m_set;
public:
  int generate();
}

int Generator::generate() {
  // Remove stale values
  auto cutoff = QDateTime::currentDateTime().addSecs(-15*60);
  auto it = m_map.begin(); // The map is sorted in ascending time order
  while (it != m_map.end() && it.key() < cutoff) {
    m_set.remove(it.value());
    it = m_map.erase(it);
  }
  // Ensure that we have some values left to find
  Q_ASSERT(m_set.size() < 10);
  // Generate a new value
  int result;
  while (true) {
    result = 1 + rand() % 10; // use C++11 random number generator instead!
    if (!m_set.contains(result)) break;
  }
  // Add it back
  m_set.insert(result);
  m_map.insert(QDateTime::currentDateTime(), result);
  return result;
}

// Look Ma, no timers! :)
```